# How to test training effect on various employee metrics?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

- I have a collection of point in time reports for employees.
- These reports contain measures of employee engagement as well as
  employee performance.
- I also have reports indicating when certain employees engaged in a
  multi month training course for managers.
- The training course has a rolling enrollment throughout the years.

I am trying to test whether or not the participation in the training course has an effect on engagement and/or performance. I find myself thinking that this calls for a cohort analysis, but I have concerns that it may be more complicated than what is needed.  Generally speaking I always seem to struggle narrowing down the appropriate testing method for a particular situation. So if you have a general guide to picking test methods, it would also be appreciated.